# Slick Slider inits when I come back to page after navigating away in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, slick.js

When I refresh the page, it works fine. But when I navigate to another page and then come back to the page, it inits again causing slides to move eratically, extra navigation to be created, etc. It doesn't reinit, it just inits everytime I navigate back to the page.
Here's my directive:

```
app.directive('slickApply', ['$timeout','$rootScope', function($timeout,  $rootScope){
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $delayTime = 1000;
            if(!$rootScope.pages){
                $delayTime = 1000;}
            else {
                $delayTime = 0;}
            $timeout(function(){
                $(element).slick(scope.$eval(attrs.slickApply));
            }, $delayTime);        
        }
    };
}]);
```

And this is my html:

```
<div class="by-the-numbers-stats" slick-apply="{centerMode: true}">
    <div ng-repeat="number_item in by_the_numbers">
        <img ng-if="number_item.image.url" src="{{number_item.image.url}}">
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I destroy plugin when I navigate to a new page and then reinit it when I come back to that page?